# Using buttons to switch views with Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having trouble switching views with button presses in my Android app. The code shows no errors in Eclipse, but the app quits unexpectedly in the emulator when the button is clicked. My code is below. Thanks

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        go.setOnClickListener(mGoListener);     
    }

    private OnClickListener mGoListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {           
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setClassName("android.taboo.Activities", "android.taboo.Activities.MainMenu");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}

public class MainMenu extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        TextView quickStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quickStart);
        quickStart.setOnClickListener(mQuickStartListener);

        TextView gameSetup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gameSetup);
        gameSetup.setOnClickListener(mGameSetupListener);

        TextView settings = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.settings);
        settings.setOnClickListener(mSettingsListener);

        TextView wordEntry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wordEntry);
        wordEntry.setOnClickListener(mWordEntryListener);
    }

    //Listeners for MainMenu navigation buttons
    private OnClickListener mQuickStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          setContentView(R.layout.quickstart);
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener mGameSetupListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          setContentView(R.layout.gamesetup);
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener mSettingsListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener mWordEntryListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          setContentView(R.layout.word);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code that i have here, this should help you out some.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SmartApp extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

        final Button firstTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstTimeButton);
        firstTimeButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent userCreationIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), UserCreation.class);
                                startActivityForResult(userCreationIntent, 0);
                        }
                });
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the "first time button" the user will be taken to the "user creation page". I believe in your code you have a few things wrong. Compare yours to what i provided and you should be able to see the differences and make the appropriate modifications. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: In what way does the startActivityForResult reference the new activity to be loaded? Here you're just passing it the intent, not a new activity

Comment: I am not completely sure. However, this method works for me and a few other people that i have helped and collaborated. Try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ok, so the Context in the intent and declaring the Views (Button in this case) as final fixed it. Plus I forgot to declare the second Activity in the AndroidManifest. Still don't fully understand why the Views need to be declared as final. Thanks for the help!